# Using SUM in a report, where the values come from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sum, oracle-apex

I am trying to produce a 'Total Cost' column in a report for a system I am developing.

The system is a Garage Management System that manages Serving and MOT appointments and produces an invoice.

The Prices come from `Job_Type` and `Parts` tables respectively and I am trying to produce a `SUM` column to create the total.

I have managed to make the **`SUM`** command work in SQL Commands using the following code.

```
SELECT SUM(JL_Price + PART_PRICE) 
  FROM GMS_Job_List, GMS_Parts, GMS_Appointments
  WHERE JL_ID=AP_Job_Type
    AND Part_ID=AP_Part_Used
    AND instr((AP_Job_ID),nvl(:JOB,AP_Job_ID))>0;
```

By selecting the appointment ID, it calculates correctly.

However, when I put it into the report query box, it gives me the total for ALL jobs and ALL parts assigned to appointments, regardless of the appointment.
How can I adapt that above statement so that it automatically recognises the row in the table. Presently, it is just saying £103.99 in every single row.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: You need to group by appointment ID

Comment: Tried Group by appointment ID, didn't work

Comment: In addition to Strawberry's suggestion, it would be easier to understand your joins between your tables if you used aliases and qualified your columns with the aliases throughout.

Comment: If it needs to be a subquery then post the full query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Sum to be grouped add the column in *group by* clause as below

```
SELECT SUM(JL_Price + PART_PRICE) , cloumn_name
    FROM GMS_Job_List, GMS_Parts, GMS_Appointments
    WHERE JL_ID=AP_Job_Type
        AND Part_ID=AP_Part_Used
       AND instr((AP_Job_ID),nvl(:JOB,AP_Job_ID))>0
    GROUP BY cloumn_name
```

here column_name i used to group the sum

Comment: This does not work, it needs to be used as a sub-query ideally."ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" This is the error I get when I try to insert it as a column in the main body as a GROUP BY AP_JOB_ID

Comment: @user3411442 if u use this query as sub query it will return an error use IN to compare instead of '=' in outer query